# Using scipy.fftpack.fft how to interprete numerical result of Fourier Transform

Tags: python, scipy, fft

The analytical Fourier transform of a sinusoidal signal is [purely imginary](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%20transform%20of%20A%20sin(bx)). However, when numerically computing discrete Fourier transform, the result is not.

Tldr: Find all answers to this question [here](http://holometer.fnal.gov/GH_FFT.pdf).

Consider therefore the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq

f_s = 200 # Sampling rate = number of measurements per second in [Hz]
t = np.arange(0,10000, 1 / f_s)
N = len(t)
A = 4 # Amplitude of sinus signal 
x = A * np.sin(t)
X = fft(x)[1:N//2]
freqs = (fftfreq(len(x)) * f_s)[1:N//2]

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex = True)
ax1.plot(freqs, X.real, label = "$\Re[X(\omega)]$")
ax1.plot(freqs, X.imag, label = "$\Im[X(\omega)]$")
ax1.set_title("Discrete Fourier Transform of $x(t) = A \cdot \sin(t)$")
ax1.legend()
ax1.grid(True)

ax2.plot(freqs, np.abs(X), label = "$|X(\omega)|$")
ax2.legend()
ax2.set_xlabel("Frequency $\omega$")
ax2.set_yscale("log")
ax2.grid(True, which = "both")
ax2.set_xlim(0.15,0.175)
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]

Clearly, the absolute value |X(w)| can be used as good approximation to the analytical result. However, the imaginary and real value of the function X(w) are different. Already  [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624548/fft-real-imaginary-abs-parts-interpretation) on SO mentioned this fact, but did not explain why. So I can only use the absolute value and the phase?

Another question would be how the Amplitude is related to the numerical result. Mathematically speaking it should be the integral under the curve of |X(w)| divided by normalization (which, as far as I understood, should be given by N), i.e. approximately by

```
A_approx = np.sum(np.abs(X)) / N
print(f"Numerical value: {A_approx:.1f}, Correct value: {A:.1f}")
```

> Numerical value: 13.5, Correct value: 4.0

This does not seem to be the case. Any insights? Ideas?

Related questions which did not help are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379536/can-you-compute-the-amplitude-power-of-original-signal-from-fourier-transform) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634666/scipy-fft-function-and-normalization-not-providing-correct-results).

Comment: These questions are more suited to the signal processing stack exchange site. To really understand how your computation is related to the (continuous time) Fourier transform, study a textbook on digital signal processing, discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT) and discrete Fourier transform (DFT).

Comment: You are right, but I didnt know such a stack exchange site would exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An FFT does not produce the result you expect because it is finite in length, and thus more similar to the Fourier Transform of a rectangular window on your sinusoid.  The length and placement of this rectangular window will affect the phase and amplitude of the FFT result.